# On RHEL 6 I seem to have EPEL installed, but it does not appear in yum. How can I activate it?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, repository

On RHEL 6 I seem to have the EPEL repository installed but it does not appear in `yum`.

1. I tested that I have EPEL installed by installing it again from the downloaded rpm:

   ```
   rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   ```

   This gives me the message: *package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed*
2. When I list all repositories available to yum via the command

   ```
   yum repolist
   ```

   however, I do not get EPEL in the output. Also when I search for packages provided by EPEl, they are not found (`aspell` dictionaries for example)
3. I tried to enable EPEL explicitly via the command-line switch `--enablerepo=epel`, but that returns a *repository not found* error.

**So, how can I install, enable or 'activate' the EPEL repository for use with `yum`?**

Comment: if you have epel rpm downloaded. then simply do force install via yum. or rpm -e epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm.

Comment: @Mongrel  Mmmmh, issuing `rpm -e epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` I get "*error: package epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm is not installed*".

Comment: @Mongrel Yes: `yum install force epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` returns the message `epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package. Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: @Mongrel Cool, that's it! The **`reinstall`** command (with epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm) does the trick! Do you write it up as an answer, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the command below which will `reinstall` the rpm.

`yum reinstall epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`